# Integrating DBT with Airflow using MWAA instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, dbt, mwaa

I was recently working on the `DBT` and `Airflow` integration on the `MWAA` instance and I followed [this official link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/samples-dbt.html) and I still struggled. Therefore, thought of posting this.

```
AIRFLOW VERSION: 2.2.2
  
DBT VERSION: 0.21.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are the hints that would help to understand this link better:

1. First of all, **don't** use their sample project. Create your own DBT project and upload that to the S3 bucket. For that create a sample directory and import that directory in the IDE and on the terminal and start with `pip3 install dbt-snowflake` (if your sink is supposed to be snowflake) if you don't have `dbt cli`.
   The second step should be `dbt init` which will prompt for a few inputs from the user like project name and sink details, creating a standard DBT project structure for you. No matter how hard you try without `profiles.yaml` you won't be able to execute anything on the `MWAA` instance.
2. Make sure that this command on your project terminal works fine before uploading the project on S3: `dbt run --project-dir . --profiles-dir .`
3. Remember that, the `S3 bucket URI` you provide to the instance it would be acting as a `/usr/local/airflow` path in the instance. So, while making the path changes in the DAG code make sure you know this.
4. Based on your sink you can decide whether you need `dbt-postgres==0.21.1`, `dbt-redshift==0.21.1` or not. Try to avoid dependencies and remove them from `requirements.txt` that won't be required for your use case.
5. Also, you need to provide this value below the `version` in the `dbt-project.yml` file-> `config-version: 2` and make sure you comment out `models` and `seeds` path for just `dbt run` command.

You can use their dag code. It's perfect. Just make sure your path is correct. These are a few of the points due to which I wasted a lot of time. Therefore, wanted to share with the community.

Comment: I'm running my dbt model from airflow-mwaa environment and it failed with the Database Error , 001003 (42000): SQL compilation error: , syntax error line 1 at position 48 unexpected '<EOF>'. , syntax error line 1 at position 47 unexpected '.'. in airflow dag logs, and surprisingly the same dbt project ran fine without any issues in my local dbt-core environment. Did any boday faced the same with dbt-core. airflow-mwaa environment.

Comment: @Govinda were you able to execute `dbt run` from local?